# Short-form notation for "Any values not null" in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following, which is written quite verbosely:

```
df.loc[
    df.group_1.notnull() | df.group_2.notnull() | df.group_3.notnull() |df.group_4.notnull(),
    ['group_1', 'group_2', 'group_3', 'group_4']
]
```

Is there a more concise way to express this?

Answer (score 2):

Let us do

```
l =  ['group_1', 'group_2', 'group_3', 'group_4']
out = df.loc[df[l].notnull().any(1), l]
```

From footfalcon

```
subdf = df.dropna(subset=l, thresh = 1)
```

Comment: why `any(1)` instead of `any(0)` ?

Comment: @carl.hiass any here is axis=1 check per row ~

Comment: perfect, just like `.apply()` ... that makes sense.

Comment: Is this the same? df.dropna(subset=['group_1', 'group_2', 'group_3', 'group_4'], how='any')

Comment: @footfalcon not the same would you mind I add this ?

Comment: @BEN_YO sure np :).  Now I see the difference, using thresh=1.